# Char is given. Array is given. If char is ‘A’ print max. If it is “B” print min. Otherwise print mean value of max and min elements

Tags: java

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class MaxMin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {-4, -3, 11, 3, 4, 4, -4, 6, -1, 9, -10, 11};
        char min = 'A';
        char max = 'B';

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            A = min(min, a[i]);
            B = max(max, a[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(min);
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask an actual question - your title is very long, but there's no text in the body of the question. Ideally, reduce your title length to a summary, and definitely give more details about what you're trying to achieve and what your code *currently* does within the question. Note that your title talks about "char" but your array is of *integers*.

Comment: The variables A and B are not defined, and the question is not clear. Please be clear and we will try to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to rearrange your code as:

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class MaxMin {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {-4, -3, 11, 3, 4, 4, -4, 6, -1, 9, -10, 11};
    int min = a[0];
    int max = a[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      min = min(min, a[i]);
      max = max(max, a[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(min);
    System.out.println(max);
  }
}
```

And in case a character is given, you can add this to your code:

```
int given_char = 'A'; // Add anything you like, A or B

switch(given_char){
  case 'A':
           System.out.println(max);
           break;
  case 'B':
           System.out.println(min);
           break;
  default:
           System.out.println( (min + max) / 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question and code is very unclear, so this is pure speculation.

It sounds as if you have an array and a char, and from that you need to either calculate the min, max or mean (of max and min) value. Your code doesn't really explain how the char is given, so I'm just assuming your taking a char value from somewhere. The code below should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {-4, -3, 11, 3, 4, 4, -4, 6, -1, 9, -10, 11};
    char c = 'A'; // This could be either 'A', 'B' or something else.       

    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        min = Math.min(min, a[i]);
        max = Math.max(max, a[i]);
    }

    if( c == 'B' )
        System.out.println(min);
    else if( c == 'A' )
        System.out.println(max);
    else
        System.out.println( (max+min) / 2.0f ); 
}
```